# Programatically set .desktop file to trusted

Tags: x11

With my application, when user clicks "Create Shortcut on Dekstop" I created a desktop file (location: `/home/noi/Desktop/mysc.desktop`) I would like to set this to be trusted programtcially (as user clicked create, otherwise they have to go to desktop right click > permissions tab > check "execute").

How can I accomplish this with X11 api? I am using Ubuntu 14 but would like a method that works across linux.

Thanks

Contents of my .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Mozilla Firefox - dev
Type=Application
Comment=Web Application
Exec=/usr/lib/firefox/firefox -P dev -no-remote
Icon=/home/noi/Desktop/test.png
```

Comment: I don't think you need the X11 API, simply set `chown noi` and `chmod +x` on the file.

Comment: X11 API has no idea about files or desktop entries or file permissions. It is centered around pushing pixels to display devices.

Comment: Thanks guys I understand better now about both X11 and `.desktop` files.